# upload image to aws ec2 with php

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to upload a file to a virtual machine in Amazon. and i have some questions.

I think i have to give (777) permissions to my server folder to be able to upload my file. if i don't it won't work. is this ok?

is it secure to give those permissions?

Comment: 777 is never secure! Why do you need to give those permissions? http://whathaveyoutried.com ?

Comment: what permissions should i give? 755 right? i need to upload images to my server

Comment: What are you using to upload these images? The answer will depend on that

Comment: im using a php function "move_uploaded_file"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to make the file's permissions 777 in order to be able to write it into a directory. Instead, the directory needs to have permission to be written to by the user.

If you are running apache, the process runs as the user `www-data` and wherever you are trying to write the file to, must have write permissions by this user. If you are writing to `/var/www/my_file_uploads`, then try this:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/my_file_uploads
```

Note that by doing this, you will be preventing others on your home machine from reading the file as well (unless you explicitly permit it).